# Image Reposition on Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am currently working on a website which uses a banner image on a profile. However if a user uploads an image the position of the banner may not be correct and they may want to change it to display the correct position of the image they want. So I have been following this guide: http://w3lessons.info/2014/08/31/facebook-style-cover-image-reposition-using-jquery-php/

I have used this guide and it works without error when I am on desktop screen sizes like 20" and above... However when ever I try to change the image position on mobile it doesn't scale correctly and the image thumb nail is not cropped correctly. But it works when the website is on a desktop because the image banner is full size... There is a demo on the website with the guide if you want to check it out and see what I am on about. I tried to see changing the crop width and height to match the mobile size but that means when it resizes back to a desktop the image is only scaled for a mobile then.

The problem is to do with:

```
$default_cover_width = 918;
$default_cover_height = 276;
```

As the screen size changes the default cover size changes as well...

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction so that I could get this working on a mobile device as well.

Thanks.

Comment: your link is broken

Comment: There we go, fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Does anyone have any idea?